# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Unreachable code

Tags: java

Can any one help me and see why the code is not working? This is the code:

```
        public class ZZ {
         public static void main(String[] args) {
             
         

              double number1 = readNumber("Enter the first number: ");

 double number2 = readNumber("Enter the second number: ");

 char operator = readOperator();

 double result = calculate(number1, number2, operator);

 System.out.println("The result is: " + result);
          }

                  
                  
                  
           public static double readNumber(String message) {
               Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
               System.out.print(message);
               return kb.nextDouble();
           }

           public static char readOperator() {
               Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
               System.out.print("Enter an operator (+, -, /, *): ");
               return scanner.next().charAt(0);
           }

           public static double calculate(double num1, double num2, char operator) {
               double result = 0.0;
               switch (operator) {
                   case '+':
                       result = num1 + num2;
                       break;
                   case '-':
                       result = num1 - num2;
                       break;
                   case '/':
                       result = num1 / num2;
                       break;
                   case '*':
                       result = num1 * num2;
                       break;
                   default:
                       System.out.println("Invalid operator!");
               }
               return result ;
               
        //the problem start from here  
               Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
           
                  System.out.println("Enter a number:")  ;
                
                 
                  double number= kb.nextDouble();
                  
                  double zakatRate = 0.025;
                  
                  double zakatAmount = number * zakatRate;
                  
                  System.out.println ("The zakat amount for " + number + " is " + zakatAmount);
                  
                  
               // Create a Scanner object for reading input 
                  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                  // Read the results of three courses
          System.out.println("Enter the result of the first course:"); 
          double course1 = scanner.nextDouble(); 
          
          System.out.println("Enter the result of the second course:");
          double course2 = scanner.nextDouble(); 
          
          System.out.println("Enter the result of the third course:"); 
          double course3 = scanner.nextDouble();
          
          
                  // Compute the semester GPA
                  double gpa = computeGPA(course1, course2, course3);
                  // Show the results
          System.out.println("The semester GPA is:" +gpa);} static double computeGPA(double course1, double course2,
              double course3) {
                  // Convert each course grade to a 4.0 scale
                  double grade1 = convertToFourPointScale(course1);
                  double grade2 = convertToFourPointScale(course2);
                  double grade3 = convertToFourPointScale(course3);

                  // Compute the average of the three grades
          double gpa = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3;
          return gpa; }
          public static double convertToFourPointScale(double grade) {
          // Convert a grade on a 0-100 scale to a 4.0 scale
                  if (grade >= 90) {
                      return 4.0; }
               else if (grade >= 80) {
                 return 3.0;  }
                else if (grade >= 70) {
                      return 2.0; }
                else if (grade >= 60) {
                      return 1.0; }
                else {
                      return 0.0;  } }
          
          
           }
```

I tried to move the code down but still not.

Comment: The error seems clear enough. Why do you expect code after `return` to do anything?

Comment: You need to format your code properly.  Especially if you want other people to try to read it.